# Is .NET supposed to implicitly bind a dependency on a certain assembly version to a newer version?

Tags: .net, dependencies, versioning

I'm wondering about .NET's defined behaviour as regards the resolution of dependencies on specific versions of assemblies. As an example, I have a dependency on `DataAccess.SQLite`, which depends on `System.Data.SQLite` 1.0.66.0. My installed version of `System.Data.SQLite`, however, is 1.0.77.0. I've found that Visual Studio 2010 will automatically inject an app.config directive to bind the `System.Data.SQLite` dependency to 1.0.77.0:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.77.0" newVersion="1.0.77.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

But, even if I remove this directive, the dependency on `System.Data.SQLite` 1.0.66.0 is apparently resolved to 1.0.77.0. *Is this the defined behaviour for .NET dependency resolution?*

I have had it happen in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project that .NET was unable to resolve the dependency as version 1.0.66.0 was not found, which is mainly why I'm asking.

Comment: Wouldn't **System.Data.SQLite** be a Microsoft compiled assembly?  I would simply update your dependency to the newer version of the dll, if you want to use Visual Studio 2010, otherwise you have to supply a local version of the older dll.

Comment: @Ramhound System.Data.SQLite is a 3rd party dependency installed by NuGet. DataAccess.SQLite is also 3rd party so I don't control which version of SQLite it depends on. Besides, if you read my question, you'll see that the dependency is in fact resolved against the newer SQLite version, so it works out.

Comment: @aknuds1, would you be able to define what you are doing which results in .net 'apparently resolving to 1.0.77.0'? I am curious because this sounds like odd behaviour. Whatever is requesting the DLL at runtime should be asking for a specific version, and I would not expect the runtime to substitute this version with another. However, if you are using something like NHibernate, and you use xml to configure System.Data.SQLite as a driver DLL, then perhaps the 1.0.77.0 version is declared here - hence more information required.

Comment: @Adam As I recall, I used CheckAsm to inspect the dependencies of a simple console program dependent on DataAccess.SQLite. The latter's dependency on System.Data.SQLite 1.0.66.0 was resolved to 1.0.77.0. Also, the program ran without problems even though System.Data.SQLite 1.0.66.0 was not installed.

Comment: So CheckAsm reported DataAccess.SQLite -> System.Data.SQLite-1.0.66.0, but when you ran the application it happily substituted it with 1.0.77.0? And this is what you mean by 'it resolved'?
Sounds odd - this is what I would do - configure the Fusion Log Viewer (ProgFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX.X\bin\FUSLOGVW.exe to report bind failures - then run your application again. Then you can use FUSLOGVW to look at all the failures. Find the one pertaining to System.Data.SQLite. It should say something like 'looking for 1.0.66.0, not found' - then it will report what it did to locate a substitute.

Comment: @Adam I think CheckAsm also showed that DataAccess.SQLite's dependency on System.Data.SQLite 1.0.66.0 was resolved to System.Data.SQLite 1.0.77.0, which is the installed version. From what I recall, in all cases, the .NET runtime would resolve System.Data.SQLite 1.0.66.0 to the installed version, i.e. 1.0.77.0. By resolution, I mean which assembly the dependency resolves against.